# Form design standard

Tags: android

One of my activities contains a form. There are 5 rows, each row has a heading, to the right, a TextView. Click the row, an appropriate ListView comes up, make your selection and it is reflected in the TextView.

I've been trying for a long time to make this form look pretty and native. Is there any system design standard for forms. Standard fonts/margins/layout/etc? Or has anybody seen an Android app with a really good form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use spinners instead of textviews and listviews for your form.  I suggest using a scrollview as your main container, have a table layout with 5 table rows.

Comment: The listviews have an option menu with a button to add an item to the list (source is SQLiteDB). When I looked into spinners, I didn't see something that could handle this need. Is there something?

Comment: I think this explains it better than I could.  Dynamically add items to spinners - http://www.designerandroid.com/?p=8